# SQL select statement accross multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are my tables: `School` `Class` `Kid`.

Each class belongs to one school.

Each kid belongs to one class.

All tables have an auto incrementing primary key.

`Class` has a foreign key pointing to the school's primary key that it belongs to. Same with `Kid` pointing to the primary key of the `Class` they belong to.

If I wanted to `select kid.id, kid.name, school.id, school.name` how would I do this in one query?

This result would return a record for each kid with their id and name. It would also include their school id and name.

```
SCHOOL
------     
id-primary     
eyname

CLASS
-----
id-primary key         
school_id-foreign key to school name

KID
---
id-primary key           
class_id-foreign key to class name
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). Do something like:

```
SELECT kid.id, kid.name, school.id, school.keyname
FROM kid
JOIN class on class.id = kid.class_id
JOIN school on school.id = class.school_id
```

Also you could do it like this:

```
SELECT kid.id, kid.name, school.id, school.name
FROM kid, class, school
WHERE class.id = kid.class_id and school.id = class.school_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select kid.id,kid.Name,school.Id,school.keyname
From kid
Inner join Class On k.Class_id = Class.Id
Inner join School On Class.school_id = school.id
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an INNER JOIN if all of the kid entities will end up mapping to a school.  A different JOIN may be needed otherwise be it a LEFT or RIGHT join.

SELECT kids.id, kids.name, schools.id, schools.name FROM kids INNER JOIN classes ON kids.class_id = classes.id INNER JOIN schools ON schools.id = classes.school_id;

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.*, c.*, k.* 
from school s 
left join class c on c.school_id=s.id
left join kid k on k.class_id=c.id
```